# File not found at path en Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel

Quiero almacenar un excel que tengo guardado en **app/storage/public/uploads** en una variable para posteriomente enviarlo como parametro a una función, el problema esta en que no logro obtener el excel con **Storage::get()** y por ende laravel me lanza un excepción:

```
Illuminate\Contracts\Filesystem\FileNotFoundException
File not found at path: storage/uploads/1633034738_1632832474_25-01 A 28-01.xls
```

Este es el campo path tal cual lo tengo guardado en la base de datos **/storage/uploads/1633034738_1632832474_25-01 A 28-01.xls**

Este es el código:

```
    public function handleImportExcelData(string $tableName, string $filePath){

        if (!$this->checkExcelColumnsFormat($tableName, $filePath)){
            return 'El formato del excel no es valido';
        }
return Storage::get('/storage/uploads/1633034738_1632832474_25-01 A 28-01.xls');

        Excel::import(new AmazonPaymentsImport(), $filePath);
```

Edit: es el proyecto de un cliente y me di cuenta que tiene creado dentro de **filesystem.php** su propio disco:

```
'excel-imports' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public/uploads'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
```

Lo comento por si afecta en algo la pregunta.

Comment: Prueba con ruta completa y absoluta, a veces las relativas dan entre problema.

Comment: cambie el nombre del archivo a test y la ruta por var/www/html/storage/app/public/uploads/1633097413_test.xls y sigo obteniendo el mismo error :c

Comment: tu ruta contiene espacios aveces esto influye mucho a la hora de buscar te recomiendo que elimines los espacios `$str = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $str);` a la hora de guardar el documento o que los remplaces por `_`

Answer (score 0):

La solución es cambiar el path el facade Storage busca al excel, en este caso cambie el disco donde esta buscando el facade Storage.

```
Storage::disk('excel-imports')->get($fileName);
```

En el caso de la pregunta, **Storage::get()** apunta al path que esta por defecto dentro de **filesystem.php** el cual por defecto en Laravel es el disco local tal cual se ve aquí:

```
'default' => env('FILESYSTEM_DRIVER', 'local'),
```

Y el disco local apunta a la carpeta **app/** y yo tenia almacenado el excel dentro de **app/storage/public/uploads**

Y mi compañero creo un disco que apunta a dicha carpeta en filesystem.php:

```
'excel-imports' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public/uploads'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ]
```

Por ende al usar el disco **excel-imports** puedo acceder al excel ya que el path apunta a su directorio.